# Does spreadsheet revision history include notes?

Tags: google-sheets

Can't find answer online or perhaps I am using wrong keywords

If a note is made in Google Sheets, will its deletion or edit be reflected in the revision history? Please cite.

Of course the foolproof way of going about this is to use comments or typing notes besides cells in different cells instead of notes, but my understanding is that comments are for notifications or more urgent or collaborative purposes while notes are just FYI.

Comment: It's easy enough to test this for yourself. Make a note on some Sheet and check the revision history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't be included in the history. Notes are available as the last version (only) of the note in relation to the cell or cells highlighted while making the note.